# Ubuntu 16.04 flickers after login when updated

Tags: drivers, nvidia, updates, macbook, flicker

I installed the 16.04.1 version into a late 2008 Macbook (5,1). Everything seemed to run smoothly until I applied the suggested updates. Since then the screen flickers and freezes right after login.

I had to reinstall Ubuntu from scratch to be able to have the laptop working again. Then I changed the Xorg default drivers to the Nvidia proprietary drivers and applied the updates but I had the same problem: not possible to go further than the login page.

Is there any other solution other than not updating the system? Or are there any drivers I can install before applying the updates?

Comment: You could always stick with the default graphics driver...

Comment: The default graphics driver does not work either after updating the system.

Comment: How are you applying the updates?

Comment: Hi. Using the Ubuntu Software center. There is a third tab called: updates. There are currently 2 updates: SO update, and software updates.

Comment: If you only do `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get upgrade` does it still break everything?

Comment: Hi Android Dev. Thanks a lot for your help. I prefer not doing the `sudo apt-get upgrade` without knowing if it's going to work. I would not like to re-install everything again.

Comment: I completely understand. Can you try upgrading the kernel, with `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`? If that causes the problem again, it's a simple fix to go into GRUB and load the older kernel.